# How to use variables as name of fields in order to update objects dynamically in Django

Tags: python, django

there are three fields in the model below in a Django app, just for example.

```
    class MyModel(models.Model):

        field1 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False,null=False)
        field2 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False,null=False)
        field3 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False,null=False)
```

In order to update multiple fields, I want to use a variable "target_field" instead of using each name of fields.

```
    for i in (1,3):
        target_field = "field{0}".format(i)
        sample_value = some_list[i]
        
        sample_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=sample_d)
        sample_object.target_field = sample_value # this couldn't work.
        sample_object.save()
```

In the code described above, "target_field" is not recognized as a name of fields.

Comment: Have you tried `sample_object[target_field] = "sample_value"`?

Comment: Did you try `target_field = getattr(sample_object, "target_field_name")`?

Comment: Thank you very much Robo-san and alirezafnatica-san. I used "setattr" instead of getattr. Regarding the advice provided Robo-san, it made a error with the message "object does not support item assignment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the field of a model just as any other attribute of a class:

```
for i in (1,3):
    target_field = "field{0}".format(i)
    sample_value = some_list[i]
        
    sample_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=sample_d)
    setattr(sample_object, target_field, sample_value)
    sample_object.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  The problem has been solved based on your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the exec() to get around it.

```
exec(sample_object+"."+target_field+"='sample value'")
```

This should work if both sample_object and target_field are strings and the object is created in main.
I have used this method to dynamically set values to variables in some of my prior projects.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  It creates TypeError with "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'sample_object' and 'str'".

Comment: I believe you need to convert the sample_object to string too, exec is basically a function that will execute a line of code in string form, although what others have suggested is better to solve this problem.

Comment: I understand your comment. I will use exec for string. Thank you.